# Given an event with probability of 0.5%, how many times do I need to repeat it to have a probability of 6%?

Tags: probability

If I am given two repeatable events -

- event A - that I am told has a probability of 0.5% to produce result X
- event B - that I am told has a probability of 6% to produce result X

and given that the events have a cost associated with them, can I approximate how many times I would expect to have to perform event A to get result X with the same probability as performing event B once?

ie. how many times would I expect to have to do event A to get a probability of 6% of producing result X, to find out if the cost of doing event A that many times works out more or less expensive than just doing event B once?

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I don't know much about probability and what to search for, the other questions of this form all seem to want to know how many times to repeat event A to get a probability of 100% with some confidence level.

Comment: Since each run of A has a chance of producing X, running A multiple times may produce multiple X. Is this a problem?

Comment: @StephanKolassa no, that would not be a problem. I'm approaching it from a perspective of a value proposition, would it in theory be better value to attempt Event A however many times, or just to attempt Event B once. Or alternatively, what cost should I assign to Event B to make it theoretically a better value proposition than doing Event A however many times. If that makes any more sense? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Dave's answer is right, but I think you can approach it in a simpler way. Think instead of the probability of NOT getting result $X$, which is $0.995$ if you try once, $0.995^2$ if you try twice.... and $0.995^n$ if you try $n$ times.

In short, you only have to solve $0.995^n = 1-0.06 = 0.94$ With $n=13$ you get under $0.94$ for the first time (93.6% chance)

Finally, there is no way to guarantee that event $A$ will produce result $X$ for any number of trials, since $0.995^n$ is always greater than zero (it actually makes sense if you think about it)

Comment: This was my first thought, but I like phrasing it in terms of expected value because that makes explicit that we're talking about having a 6% chance on average. It does concern me, however, that this methods gives 13 and mine gives 12...continuity vs discreteness issue?

Comment: The result was "12.something" with that something being small, but since $n$ must be an integer, I rounded up the result. The 6% chance is a 6% chance every single time you repeat the experiment, there is no average there

Comment: I agree with rounding up to 13. What I'm wondering is why my approach results in exactly 12, while the calculation you did results in 12.something.

Comment: Could you please provide further details about how you get 12 as the answer?

Comment: N = 0.06/P = 0.06/0.005 = 12

Comment: @Dave I don't know where that formula comes from, but please note that, for N>200, you get a probability of having result X which is higher than 1

Comment: That's the expected value of a binomial distribution. If we want a a 6% chance of success in N trials, that's an expected value of 0.06 for six successes in 100 trials, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95434/discussion-between-dave-and-david).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it's not a problem if X happens more than once, you can just reverse the probability and calculate the answer very simply.  If event A has a 0.5% chance of producing result X, that means it has a 99.5% chance of *not* producing result X.  How many times do you need to multiply 99.5% (i.e. 0.995) by itself, to get down to 94% (0.94) ?  Let *t* be the number of times:

$0.995^t = 0.94$

$log(0.995)t = log(0.94)$

$t = \frac{log(0.94)}{log(0.995)}$

$t = \frac{-0.0268721464}{-0.00217691925}$

$t = 12.3441171957$

Since *t* needs to be a whole number, you set it equal to 13.  Now you can check your answer:

$0.995^{13} = 0.93691469288$

That means if you repeat event A 13 times, you have a 6.3% chance ($1-0.93691469288$) of result X happening at least once.

Comment: Correct, having it happen more than once is not a problem. Thanks